# Ignoring/Losing Immunities- How does this work, exactly?

Tags: dnd-4e

The power Wizard's Wrath contains the following text:

> **Effect**: The burst becomes a zone of arcane energy that lasts until the end of your next turn. You gain combat advantage against targets in the zone, and they lose all immunities and resistances against your attacks.

Slightly different, but similar is the feat Paladin's Truth:

> When you attack a creature marked by you, you ignore that creature’s resistances and immunities.

Obviously this applies to instantaneous things- a monster immune to fire would take fire damage, for example.  What about things that continue?  If you had, for example, a power that Dazed until the end of your next turn, or for that matter (Save Ends), and attacked an enemy who was Immune to Dazed, would they remain dazed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this question is very complex to answer depending only on RAW. But let's start with the definition of a [immunity](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=646), as stated on Rules Compendium, pg 225:

> A creature that is immune to a condition or another effect (such as the dazed condition or forced movement) is unaffected by the stated effect.

I also assume we are not talking about ongoing damage on a creature immune to that damage type, as covered on [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69165/do-you-still-count-as-taking-ongoing-damage-if-youre-resisting-the-damage). So, let's focus on effects and go on parts.

Notice that the feat Paladin's Truth don't have a *duration* on itself. It is not "lose all immunities until the end of your next turn" or something like that. Under that reading, I understand that those specific entries allow the effect to go through its normal duration, regardless of immunity.

Wizard's Wrath, on the other hand, is a lot more complex. First, the effect list *"targets within the zone"*, but the power itself have no target line. Common sense dictates that this is referencing to the target of the follow-up power you will use, not this power itself.  The power also states the *"target lose immunity against your attacks"*, and not something like *"loses immunities while within the zone"*.

It is not as clear as the feat, but my interpretation is that the immunity-loss stay as long as the effect last as well.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, Immunity as defined in the back of the Monster Manual:

> The monster has immunity to the stated kind of damage or effect. For example, a monster with “immune poison” never takes poison damage and can’t suffer any other ill effect from a poison attack.

So the book doesn't give a clear answer about immunity to conditions, and it'll likely depend on DM interpretation.

But if it came up in my game, my ruling would be that the condition persists: immunity to Dazed means that the Dazed condition cannot be *imposed* on them, so if something "got past" their immunity and affected them anyway, they'd continue to suffer its effects until they saved against it or the duration expired.

Conversely, if a monster was usually immune to fire and taking ongoing fire damage, that damage would effectively cease when the immunity "turned on" again: they are still affected by the "ongoing 5 fire" or whatever, but it does no actual damage to them. If their immunity is compromised again before the effect ceases, it starts hurting again. (Think about Fezzik being set on fire near the end of *The Princess Bride*. He is actually on fire, it's just not actually hurting him because of Max's cloak. But if the cloak suddenly got magicked away, that fire's still there.)

Comment: There is a more complete description of Immunity on Rules Compendium, pg 225, that expand on immunity to specific status effects.